# JSP Dropdown list from database

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsp, jpa

just a newbie question, i am currently developing a system and it has a form that needs to be filled out by the users,

I'm planning on populating several dropdown lists using data extracted from the database using hibernate.

The question is, would it be wise if I do that? let's assume that i have 3-4 dropdowns that would each have 50-100+ options coming from the database. will it encounter performance issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data-driven performance problems aren't new and Most of the time it’s related to too much data queried from the database.
   There are tons of good resources on "Optimization".

Overview of link below:
If you’re doing ORM, Hibernate etc..There are some basics to keep your options open when it comes to performance:

Don’t do explicit flushing

Don’t disable lazy loading in your mappings

Don’t use Session.clear()

Hibernate performance

The way Hibernate basically promises to deliver performance is through caching and changing the amount of data that is fetched each time. This works for most of the cases where you use Hibernate. If not, you might just need to do some good old SQL.

http://blog.f12.no/wp/2010/02/16/hibernate-performance-and-optimization/

I had a particular performance issue last year, what worked for me was moving UI processing/loading to the client with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off allowing users to search within the dropdown and filtering the results once they have entered a certain minimum amount of characters (say 3 or 4).

With that number of results you will likely need filtering anyway, and doing it this way means you are not loading all of the data at once, and you are only loading the data that is needed.

Comment: yeah i'm using a dropdown with a search filter. but how would you achieve not loading all data at once? i'm planning to use jstl to populate the dropdown list but that would load all the data at once.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how it would work using java, but basically you would query the database on each key press and filter the results based on what has been entered. You could then limit this to maybe the first 10 or 20 results which would be refined as the user enters more characters. While it's not java, take a look at the "Loading remote data" example for select2: https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: I see. I'll check that out first. Thanks.